# How can I write a loop to automatically impute missing values in longitudinal data, based on the previous and next observed values?

Tags: r

I have a longitudinal dataset with many missing values that I would like automatically imputed in R based on the 'last observed value' carried forward, and the 'next observed value' carried backwards. Similar questions have been asked previously, but I would like to add specific conditions for imputation based on the length of the gaps.

The following data frame (wide format) demonstrates the issue:

```
miss.df <- data.frame(id = c('A','B','C','D','E'),
                      w1 = c(1,1,2,2,1),
                      w2 = c(1,NA,NA,2,NA),
                      w3 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,2),
                      w4 = c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                      w5 = c(1,2,NA,1,3),
                      w6 = c(1,2,1,NA,NA))
```

As so:

```
  id w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6
1  A  1  1 NA  1  1  1
2  B  1 NA NA NA  2  2
3  C  2 NA NA NA NA  1
4  D  2  2 NA NA  1 NA
5  E  1 NA  2 NA  3 NA
```

Please note that the data is in wide format, so w1 is the first wave, etc. The first wave is complete with no missings. The values are the numeric values for a categorical variable (political party preference). There is no order to the categories. This data frame therefore consists of information on only one variable, on five individuals across six waves.

The conditions I would like are as follows:

1. If the gap consists of only one missing, carry last observed value forward, including cases where the gap is in the final wave.
2. If the gap is an **even** number of missings (id = C, for instance), then carry forward and carry back so that the values 'meet in the middle'. As such, it is assumed that the individual transitioned (i.e. changed category) half-way through.
3. If the gap is an **odd** number of missings (id = B, for instance), then carry forward and carry back to meet in the middle, as point 2, but the exact middle value is imputed as the carry forward value.

If one was to run a loop with the above conditions, the data frame would look like this:

```
  id w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6
1  A  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  B  1  1  1  2  2  2
3  C  2  2  2  1  1  1
4  D  2  2  2  1  1  1
5  E  1  1  2  2  3  3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. Tricky. And I don't know of any useful R generic for filling in NAs. In the end I thought the easiest way was a good old `for` loop. The logic is to fill in one from the left, then one from the right, and to repeat this until everything is filled in. Not very R at all - it could practically be C code - but should be fine unless you have a zillion rows.

```
fill_in_old_skool <- function (r) {  
  while (anyNA(r)) {
    for (idx in seq_along(r)) {
      val <- r[idx] 
      if (is.na(r[idx]) && idx > 1) r[idx] <- lastval
      lastval <- val
    }
    for (idx in rev(seq_along(r))) {
      val <- r[idx]
      if (is.na(r[idx]) && idx < length(r)) r[idx] <- lastval
      lastval <- val
    }
  }
  r
}

miss.df[,-1] <- t(apply(miss.df[,-1], 1, fill_in_old_skool))
```

Comment: This works exactly as intended, thank you. Let us say that I do NOT want to impute missing values at the 'end' of each wave, or missing values that never have an observed value in a subsequent wave. So, in the example I gave originally, the loop would impute all values apart from wave 6 of observations D and E, which would remain missing. For instance, a preliminary loop could be ran that imputes '999' for missings from right to left, until it hits an observed value. Then your original loop could be ran, followed by a simple recode from '999' back to missing.

Answer (score 0):

The **imputeTS** package has a function that is very similar, to what you want to do.

The function is called **na_ma(x, k = 2, weighting = "simple")**.

> Missing Value Imputation by Weighted Moving Average

Basically what it does for you is:
If you input a time series **x**, it looks for the **k** next values and takes their average as values for imputation.

Not exactly what you described, but I think it might resemble the idea behind your proposed procedure.